# Question of maximum likelihood estimation.

Tags: statistics

A population density function is definded as $$
f(s)=\begin{cases} 
(W-1)s^{-W} & s\geq 1, \\
0& \text{elsewhere},
\end{cases}
$$

where $W>1$ is unknown. I just want to ask, how do i find the maximum likelihood estimator of $W$? Do I do the normal differentiation of this function first, and then do a 2nd order differentiation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Pareto distribution.

You omit to say what sort of data you've got.  I'm going to take a leap and guess you mean an i.i.d. sample, whose size let us call $n$.  Then you've got
$$
\ell(W)=\log L(W) = \log\Big((W-1)^n (s_1\cdots s_n)^{-W} \Big) = n\log(W-1)-W\log(s_1\cdots s_n).
$$
So
$$
\ell\,'(W) = \frac{n}{W-1} - \log(s_1\cdots s_n).
$$
$$
= \frac{n-(W-1)\log(s_1\cdots s_n)}{W-1} \qquad \begin{cases} >0 & \text{if }1<W<\frac{n}{\log(s_1\cdots s_n)} +1, \\[12pt]
=0 & \text{if }W=\frac{n}{\log(s_1\cdots s_n)} +1, \\[12pt]
<0 & \text{if }W>\frac{n}{\log(s_1\cdots s_n)} +1 .\end{cases}
$$
(Notice that to find these intervals, one needs to consider only the numerator, since the denominator is always positive.)

So $\widehat W = \dfrac{n}{\log(s_1\cdots s_n)}+1$.

Comment: Fixed. ${{{{{{{{}}}}}}}}$

Comment: One can also note that $\mathbb E_W(\log S)=W-1$ hence $\widehat W_n\to W$ almost surely when $n\to\infty$..

Comment: Perhaps. . . . . .  But in practice $n$ will never approach $\infty$ and it may be of more interest to examine the probability distribution of $\widehat W$ for small $n$.

Comment: Not always--but anyway my point was rather to check that the result for $\widehat W_n$ was not too unreasonable.

Comment: You could have an estimator that's very unreasonable for small $n$ but approaches the right limit as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Yeeeess... I knoooow... Nevertheless, wondering what is the almost sure behaviour of an estimator when $n\to\infty$ may help to spot computation mistakes (for example this is how I instantly knew that your first answer was wrong, before determining the exact mistake you had made).

Comment: I see. ${{{{{{}}}}}}$

Comment: thanks for this. much appreciated. sorry for not mentioning that the sample data are random from the same population.